# How can I merge ...object and return value of function call in setState(react-hook)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can't merge ...state and result of function return.

I'm try to changing class component to function component.

so I updated react and used hook.

first of all I want to change class's state, setState to hook's those.

but hook's setState replace oject not merging like class' setState.

It is original code below

```
import React from 'react'
import produce from 'immer'
import {
  getUserFromCookie,
  login,
  logout,
  profile,
  updateProfile
} from '../api'

const userInfo = getUserFromCookie()
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  ...userInfo
})

export const withUserContext = WrappedComponent => {
  return class ProviderComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        ...userInfo,
        consentNeeded: false,
        updateConsent: async ({ pi, news, seen }) => {
          await updateProfile({ pi, news, seen })
          this.setState({
            consentNeeded: false
          })
        },
        profile: async () => {
          const userProfile = await profile()
          if (userProfile.seen_consent_modal === false) {
            this.setState({
              consentNeeded: true
            })
          }
        },
        login: async ({ userId, password }) => {
          const user = await login({ userId, password })
          this.setState(
            produce(draft => {
              return user
            })
          )
        },
        logout: async () => {
          await logout()
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default UserContext
```

and It is function Component I worked.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import produce from 'immer'
import {
  getUserFromCookie,
  login,
  logout,
  profile,
  updateProfile
} from '../api'

const userInfo = getUserFromCookie()
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  ...userInfo
})

export const withUserContext = WrappedComponent => {
  return function provideComponent() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
      ...userInfo,
      consentNeeded: false,
      updateConsent: async ({ pi, news, seen }) => {
        console.error('updateConsent!!')
        await updateProfile({ pi, news, seen })
        setState({
          consentNeeded: false
        })
      },
      profile: async () => {
        console.error('profile!!')
        const userProfile = await profile()
        if (userProfile.seen_consent_modal === false) {
          setState({
            consentNeeded: true
          })
        }
      },
      login: async ({ userId, password }) => {
        const user = await login({ userId, password })

        setState(
          produce(() => user)
        )
      },
      logout: async () => {
        await logout()
      }
    })

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={state}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default UserContext
```

underline warning.. I think it is not correct syntax

Comment: why do you put `async` function inside of initial `state`'s value? how do you expect them to be called? and when? better attach your source class-based component(but not everything - just single `state`'s key and function that loads that would be enough)

Comment: by now I can say looks like misusing `useState` - it's argument is initial value of some state data just like you may initialize that for class-based components in constructor: `this.state = { .... };` based on props. The same is here. So typically you don't want to have functions there.

Comment: I advice you, for complex components use class component ! functional component has different use case ... here you should write {...state, *****} and not {...userInfo, *****}

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

I realized what is the problem. I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-http-vt7i9) with everything working (except by the functions you didn't provided).

### 1. `HOC`s should be used for `Contex.Consumer` Not `Context.Provider`

In your code, you are making a `HOC` for `Context.Provider` but the correct way should be for `Contex.Consumer`.

To work with context, you need

```
<Contex.Provider>
    ...
    <AnyThingYouWant>
        <Context.Consumer>
        </Context.Consumer>
    </AnyThingYouWant>
</Contex.Provider>
```

If you want a `HOC` for `Contex.Provider`, you only need to use `children` and wrap it around your components

e.g.

```
const UserContext = React.createContext('my context')

const UserProvider = (props) => {

    const value = useState('someState')

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

### 2. If you are using functional components, you don't need `HOC` anymore.

React Hooks introduced [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Now the only thing you need to render the `Context.Provider` and use it like so `const {...contextValue} = useContext(MyContext)`.

e.g.

```
const { updateConsent, profile, login, logout, ...otherStuff } = useContex(UserContext)
```

### 3.Inside `Context.Consumer` you need to pass a function that render the `WrappedComponent`

When making a `HOC` for `Context.Consumer`, you need to have a function that renders the `WrappedComponent` and reciveis the `props` from the consumer.

e.g.

```
const withUserContext = WrappedComponent => {
  return function UserContextHoc(props) {
    return (
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        // function that render the `WrappedComponent`
        {consumerProps => <WrappedComponent {...props} {...consumerProps} />}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
};
```

If you do something like this, it's wrong

```
<UserContext.Consumer>
    // THIS IS WRONG AND WILL THROW AN ERROR
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

If you look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-http-vt7i9) you will see that it gives no errors and also, in the `console` inside `MyComponent`, it shows everything that is from the `UserContext`.

Hope now everything is more clear.

---

## Old:

Your functions should be out side of `useState` initial value to be able to call `setState`.

```
// state has multiple key value
 const [state, setState] = useState({
      ...userInfo,
      consentNeeded: false,      
    })
const updateConsent = async ({ pi, news, seen }) => {
        await updateProfile({ pi, news, seen })
        setState({
          consentNeeded: false
        })
      }

const profile = async () => {
        const userProfile = await profile()
        if (userProfile.seen_consent_modal === false) {

          // setState(prevState => {
          //   return {...prevState, {consentNeeded: true}};
          // });
          setState({
            consentNeeded: true
          })
        }
      }

const login = async ({ userId, password }) => {
        const user = await login({ userId, password })
        // code below change it as produce's result. 
        // not merging of exist states

        // setState(
        //   produce(() => {
        //     return user
        //   })
        // )

       // what I've tried.. but warning underline..
        setState(prevState => {...prevState, produce(() => user)})
}

const logout = async () => {
    await logout()
}

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{
        ...state,
        updateConsent,
        profile,
        login,
        logout,
      }>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
```

Comment: Line 90:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
```javascript
  88 |     const user = await login({ userId, password })
  89 | 
> 90 |     setState(prevState => {...prevState, produce(()=>user)})
     |                            ^
  91 |   }
  92 |   const logout = async () => {
  93 |     await logout()
```

it doesn't work...

Comment: @sunheekyung can you post the full code in your question? The full code of your component. If you are getting unexpected token, it's just some syntax problem, easy to fix

Comment: I posted original code and that Im working on but doesn't work well

Comment: @sunheekyung I just edit my answer with full working example and much better explanations, hope it helps now!